# Change size of MaskedLayer over UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have two `UIImageViews` that occupy the whole screen meaning their frames are : **(0,0,320,480)**.
`imageView2` is on top of `imageView1`.

They both have masks applied to them using `CAShapeLayer`. I have made a function

```
-(void)addMask:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIImageView*)imageView
```

which is as follows

```
//Function
-(void)addMask:(CGRect)rect toView:(UIImageView*)imageView {

CAShapeLayer * shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];

CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, NULL);
shapeLayer.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);

imageView.layer.mask=shapeLayer;
imageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;

}
```

I am applying the masks over the `UIImageViews` in `viewDidAppear` using the following `CGRects`:

```
//In view did Appear
[self addMask:CGRectMake(0,0,160,480) toView:self.imageView];
[self addMask:CGRectMake(160,0,160,480) toView:self.imageView2];
```

So the result is the screen is half split showing half `imageView1` on left side and half `imageView2` on right side.

I have a button that is hooked up with `IBAction(buttonPressed:)`.

What I want to achieve is when the button is pressed the mask of the `imageView1` is increased while that of mask of `UIImageView2` is decreased : so that `imageView1` on the left occupy 75% of the screen while `imageView2` on the right occupty 25% of the screen. What I am trying to do right now is in code below but that is not getting the desired results:

```
//In IBAction
CGRect tmpRect ;
tmpRect = imageView1.layer.frame;
NSLog(@"Rect1  : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(tmpRect));
tmpRect.size.width+=20.0;
[self addMask:tmpRect toView:self.imageView];

tmpRect= imageView2.layer.frame;
NSLog(@"Rect2 : %@",NSStringFromCGRect(tmpRect));
tmpRect.origin.x+=20.0;
tmpRect.size.width-=20.0;
[self addMask:tmpRect toView:self.imageView2];
```

The output is

```
2013-08-26 13:15:41.753 imageMasking[16191:c07] Rect1  : {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
2013-08-26 13:15:41.754 imageMasking[16191:c07] Rect2 : {{0, 0}, {320, 460}}
```

Heres the picture view of what I m trying to achieve.

[image]

Also later on I would like to move the masks using the `panGesture`. So is it a good idea to apply masks a thousand times while your fingers are being dragged using this function ?
 Is there any other alternative to what I am trying to achieve as I might be entirely wrong in my approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that on your button press you are always going to `layer.frame` which is the full frame of the image view, not the current frame that you are masking to. You should store the position of your split line, just as a `CGFloat`, in a property and as you want to modify the mask, first update this property and then use it to calculate the new mask paths.

You shouldn't worry about performance until you have a reason to. I.e usage / testing tells you that you need to make a change. Then you should profile to find out what is causing the problem and then work on that.

That said, you shouldn't need to create a new shape layer each time, just update the path.

Comment: Thanks Wain. 

Thats what I thought

So going forward I will have several rects rather than just one and a single line wont suffice. 

So now I making a NSMutableArray of rects such as

     _rects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"{{0, 0}, {160, 460}}",@"{{160, 0}, {160, 460}}", nil];

Converting CGRectFromString to use the actual rects. 

Thanks
Waris